# Software manager removed package but it still appears as installed

Tags: package-management, software-center, delete

Using the Software manager (briefcase icon in apps) I installed Calibre then decided to uninstall it the same way by clicking "Remove".

The app no longer appears in Apps and after running  `dpkg --list`  there was no trace of it either.

Yet it is still listed under my installed apps in Software (briefcase icon in apps).

It cannot be launched, nor can it be removed.

I've run  `apt-get autoremove`  and  `apt-get purge`  commands but get a response that the package is not installed so cannot be removed.

There are a about 15 files installed across *usr/bin*, *usr/share* and *var/lib/app-info* and about 15 in *snap* as well, but none of them can be deleted when right clicked.

This is hardly a matter of life or death but it does annoy the hell out of me.

Any ideas how to remove apps from Software that have been removed but remain on the installed list?

Comment: Edit your question to provide a specific example of software installed from a deb that cannot be removed by the Ubuntu Software application. And another example of software installed from a Snap that cannot be removed by the Ubuntu Software application. We cannot work with "about 15", but we can show you how to troubleshoot and fix one of each.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i calibre`; `snap list | grep -i calibre` ; `flatpak list | grep -i calibre` to the question.